# altering a string with PHP

Tags: php, string

If I have filename.jpg, with PHP how would change it too filename123456789.jpg, where 123456789 is a timestamp, I currently do this,

```
$name = $filename;
$parts = explode(".", $name);
$filename = $parts[0].time().'.'.$parts[1];
```

however this just just leaves me with 123456789.

Comment: note that there can be more dots in the file name

Comment: Can anyone explain me the reason of upvoting this question?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, it's something I am often required to do, and would like to know best practices as there are a plethora of different string manipulation methods available in PHP. They all have there respective drawbacks and performance penalties afterall; that a good enough explanation for you sir?

Comment: Iterating a directory would result in `.`, followed by `..`, only then followed by all other files.  These two filenames indeed result in the said timestamp, prepended and followed by nothing.

Comment: @pharalia this question is not about string manipulation but it actually asks why working code doesn't work. It's about some mistype the OP did in their other code. And these performance penalties you're mention are bullshit. Friggin **disk write** will take zillion times more time than this crappy "string operation"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your approach works fine too, but breaks if the filename has multiple dots. I'd rather use the pathinfo() function to accomplish this:

```
$info = pathinfo($filename);
$filename = $info['filename'].time().'.'.$info['extension'];
```

Answer (score 0):

debug (output) your input and steps to find the error

```
function debug($var, $label = '') {
    echo $label
        . '<pre>'
        . print_r($var, true)
        . '</pre>';
}

$name = 'filename.bug.test.jpg';
debug($name, 'old filename');
$parts = explode('.', $name);
debug($parts, 'filenameparts');
$ext = array_pop($parts);
$prefix = implode('.', $parts);
$newName = $prefix . time() . '.' . $ext;
debug($newName, 'new filename');
```

as mention above use `pathinfo` instead of `explode`

i've used `explode`, couse i've used a dummy filename.

Answer (score 0):

thats a no-brainer:

```
function getFileName($filename){
preg_match('#([^/]+)\.([\w]+)$#',$filename,$match);
return $match[1].time().'.'.$match[2];
}
```

Comment: why involve preg_match() when pathinfo() exists?

Comment: cause somebody else already did it, many roads lead to rome and all that